# Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 - MCPConnection

Tags: xcode, linker, linker-errors, i386

Today i installed the MCPConnetion for mysql.

i just copied the source code to my app.

then, i call the code:

```
#import "MCPConnection.h"
```

and worked with hem:

```
MCPConnection *connection = [[MCPConnection alloc] initToHost:@"localhost" withLogin:@"root" usingPort:8889];
```

and Xcode give me a ERROR:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MCPConnection", referenced from:
Objc-class-ref in DetailViewController.o
Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What i do not currently?

(Xcode 4.4 DP2, Mountain Lion DP2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the project is not including the necessary framework. Go to your Target -> Build Phases -> Link and verify that in fact you have The framework that contains MCPConnection there.